# Minecraft forge mod compiling error

Tags: java, macos

I have made a mod and now i want to compile it i followed a tutorial and tried to compile however i have an error. Please tell me what i did wrong.
Thank you.

Terminal:

```
* Where:
Build file '/Users/Will/Dropbox/forge/build.gradle' line: 20

* What went wrong:
Could not compile build file '/Users/Will/Dropbox/forge/build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  build file '/Users/Will/Dropbox/forge/build.gradle': 20: Invalid variable name. Must start with a letter but was: “1”
  . At [20:11]  @ line 20, column 11.
     version = “1”
               ^

  1 error


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 6.669 secs
```

Build.grade:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            name = "forge"
            url = "http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven"
        }
        maven {
            name = "sonatype"
            url = "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'forge'

version = “1”
group = “com.candymod.mincoder”
archivesBaseName = “Candymod”

minecraft {
    version = "1.7.10-10.13.2.1230"
    runDir = "eclipse"
}

dependencies {
    // you may put jars on which you depend on in ./libs
    // or you may define them like so..
    //compile "some.group:artifact:version:classifier"
    //compile "some.group:artifact:version"

    // real examples
    //compile 'com.mod-buildcraft:buildcraft:6.0.8:dev'  // adds buildcraft to the dev env
    //compile 'com.googlecode.efficient-java-matrix-library:ejml:0.24' // adds ejml to the dev env

    // for more info...
    // http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html
    // http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html

}

processResources
{
    // this will ensure that this task is redone when the versions change.
    inputs.property "version", project.version
    inputs.property "mcversion", project.minecraft.version

    // replace stuff in mcmod.info, nothing else
    from(sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs) {
        include 'mcmod.info'

        // replace version and mcversion
        expand 'version':project.version, 'mcversion':project.minecraft.version
    }

    // copy everything else, thats not the mcmod.info
    from(sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs) {
        exclude 'mcmod.info'
    }
}
```

Thank you if you decide to help.

Comment: Aside from anything else, if you really have `“` instead of `"` that may well be the problem. Use simple double-quotes, not "curly quotes"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using a [mac](/questions/tagged/mac), which I assume you are from your path and using the horrible TextEdit program, then you need to go into settings and [turn off "smart quotes"](http://scttdvd.com/post/65242711516/how-to-get-rid-of-smart-quotes-osx-mavericks).  The "Smart Quotes" functionality in TextEdit automatically exchanges normal quotes `"` for quotation quotes `“` while you type.

i.e.

```
version = “1”
```

should be

```
version = "1"
```

Subtle difference, but it's there.  You'll get the same problem wherever else these are used, e.g.

```
group = “com.candymod.mincoder”
archivesBaseName = “Candymod”
```

**Longer term solution**

Get a coding oriented editor such as [Sublime](http://www.sublimetext.com) to replace your use of TextEdit which has many advantages including navigation and syntax colouring to make coding easier.

Comment: Thank you for the help. A bit late to say thank you i guess but thank you.